# MVC application @html.ActionLink return the resource could not be found why?

Tags: javascript, html, css, model-view-controller

i have a mvc asp.net web application, i need to create new view in this app

i add a controller, and new view named Index as below

```
@model IEnumerable<GYMONE.Models.ContactModel>

   @using GridMvc.Html
    @{
      ViewBag.Title = "Drivers Details";        
      <div class="container">
 <div class="clearfix"></div>
    <fieldset>
        <legend class="legend">Drivers Details</legend>

    <div class="panel">

        <div class="panel-body">


     
    </div>

</fieldset>
```

i am trying to navigate to this view using the url below

```
     @Html.ActionLink("All Contacts ", "Index", "Contacts")
```

but the browser return

```
Server Error in '/' Application.
  The resource cannot be found.
```

Comment: make sure that there get action named "index" in the controller Contacts